# MVC Bootstrap Partial View ValidationMessageFor execute on loading Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, partial-views

Im am doing an `MVC`, `Bootstrap App`.

I open a `Bootstrap` `Partial View from Jquery` passing `Model` as Parameter.

From `Controller` I return `Partial View` and I open it from Jquery.

The Problem I found, is that `ValidationMessageFor` is executed wh`en Partial View` is loaded... I can not find why.

The process is like this... I have an Image that called a JavaScript function...

> img id="btnEmail" src="~/Content/Images/Email.png"  onclick="btnEmail('param1',Param2)"

Here is My `Jquery`

```html
  function btnEmail(nick, user_id) {
       --validate if user is logged and call function that call Partial View
        if (SearchLogin())
            SendMail();
    }

 function SendMail() {

            user_id = $('#CommentUser_id').val();
            nick = $('#LblCommentName').val();
            if (user_id == $('#User_id').val())
                return;

            var model = { Object_id: $("#Upload_id").val(), Nick: nick, UserDestination_id: $("#User_id").val(), Parent_id: null, UserOrigin_id: user_id};
            $.ajax(
                      {
                          type: "POST",
                          url: '@Url.Action("Email", "Contact")',
                          data: model,
                          success: function (result) {
                              $("#myModalContact").html(result).modal({ backdrop: "static" });
                          },
                         
                      });
            "static" });
        }
```

Here is my

```
Controller Method
```

```html
 public async Task<ActionResult> Email(ContactModel model)
        {
            return PartialView("_Contact", model);
        }
```

And Here is my Partial View

If I called my Partial View like this

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalContact" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Contact/_Contact.cshtml", new TableAvivaVoz.Models.ContactModel() { Object_id = Model.upload.Upload_id, Nick = Model.upload.Nick, UserDestination_id = Model.upload.User_id, Parent_id = null,UserOrigin_id=Model.User_id });
    </div>
```

it Works fine...

here is part of My Partial View

```html
@model  TableAvivaVoz.Models.ContactModel
@{
    AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "sucessContact",
    };
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("XXX", "Contact", ajaxOpts))
{
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                   
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="myPartialContact">
                <div class="alert alert-success hidden">
                </div>
            </div>
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
           
            <div style="padding-bottom:220px">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, 10, 80, new { @class = "txtDescQ", placeholder = "Ingresa un mensaje", @rows = 8, onclick = "OcultarRecomend();" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="myPartialContactBtn modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default visible btnOk" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary visible btnOk" id="btnSave">Enviar</button>

                </div>

            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: what calls the javascript function `SendMail()`?

Comment: zgood... SendMail is called from another JavaScript that does some. validation... The first javascrpit function is called from Image click... I am going to update the post. Tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get errors on load because you are passing a erroneous Model to the action `Email(ContactModel model)`. 
When you ajax post, the Model binder validates the model and adds errors to the model state.

To fix this do as below:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Email(ContactModel model)
{
     ModelState.Clear();    
     return PartialView("_Contact", model);
}
```

Let me know if it helps.